# Oracle SQL, how to filter on a set by a rank?

Tags: oracle

I am struggling with the following SQL query right now:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/736a7/12

```
select uc.*
from usercredential uc
inner join users u on u.userid = uc.userid
inner join credential c on c.credentialid = uc.credentialid
inner join healthsystemcredential hsc on hsc.credentialid = c.credentialid
inner join accesslevel ac on hsc.hscredentialid in (
  -- Trying to figure out how to filter here?
  select 1 from dual
)
where c.fulfillmentmethod = 'Attach'
and c.display = 1
and uc.auditstatus <> 0
and ( (uc.auditstatus is null) or (uc.auditstatus = 1 and uc.lastmodified > uc.auditdate) )
```

Basically I am trying to get UserCredential that are Many To One with Credential.  Credential is One To Many with HealthSystemCredential.

The HealthSystemCredential has a foreign key to AccessLevel, however this AccessLevel column in HealthSystemCredential is actually the Lowest Allowable Access Level.  AccessLevel records have a Type Rank between 1 at the lowest and 4 at the highest.

> Example: A HealthSystemCredential with an AccessLevel record that has a Type Rank of 2 should be fetched when I filter my query by AccessLevels with Types of 2, 3, or 4.

The problem is I can't figure out how to do this in one query.  Is there some way I can get a DENSE_RANK column in a subquery of AccessLevels, apply my filter in the subquery and join it to the table somehow to give me all the applicable HealthSystemCredentials I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually several ranking functions you can use. You can read at the [Analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm#i81407) at Oracle documentation. In your case, `RANK()` and `DENSE_RANK()` would work, if I have understood you:

```
select *
from
  ( select uc.*,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ac.HEALTHSYSTEMID
                              ORDER BY ac.ACCESSLEVELTYPE ASC) 
             AS drnk
    from usercredential uc
      inner join users u 
              on u.userid = uc.userid
      inner join credential c 
              on c.credentialid = uc.credentialid
      inner join healthsystemcredential hsc 
              on hsc.credentialid = c.credentialid
      inner join accesslevel ac 
              on hsc.HEALTHSYSTEMID = ac.HEALTHSYSTEMID 
    where c.fulfillmentmethod = 'Attach'
    and c.display = 1
    and uc.auditstatus <> 0
    and ( (uc.auditstatus is null) 
       or (uc.auditstatus = 1 and uc.lastmodified > uc.auditdate) 
        ) 
  ) tmp
where drnk = 1 ;
```

The condition on `drnk = 1` (lowest Type Rank) will be applied of course after the other conditions in the internal `where` are applied. If you want to first filter on the lowest Type Rank (this may give you less rows in the final result), you can either group by in a derived table and then join:

```
select uc.*
from usercredential uc
  inner join users u 
          on u.userid = uc.userid
  inner join credential c 
          on c.credentialid = uc.credentialid
  inner join healthsystemcredential hsc 
          on hsc.credentialid = c.credentialid
  inner join ( SELECT HEALTHSYSTEMID,
                      MIN(ACCESSLEVELTYPE) AS ACCESSLEVELTYPE 
               FROM accesslevel 
               GROUP BY HEALTHSYSTEMID
             ) ac 
          on hsc.HEALTHSYSTEMID = ac.HEALTHSYSTEMID 
where c.fulfillmentmethod = 'Attach'
and c.display = 1
and uc.auditstatus <> 0
and ( (uc.auditstatus is null) 
   or (uc.auditstatus = 1 and uc.lastmodified > uc.auditdate) 
    ) ;
```

or use a subquery in the `ON` clause. This is closer to your try but quite complicated. SQL-Server has `CROSS APPLY` which makes this kind of joins more easy to write:

```
select uc.*
from usercredential uc
  inner join users u 
          on u.userid = uc.userid
  inner join credential c 
          on c.credentialid = uc.credentialid
  inner join healthsystemcredential hsc 
          on hsc.credentialid = c.credentialid
  inner join accesslevel ac
          on ac.HEALTHSYSTEMID = hsc.HEALTHSYSTEMID
         and ac.ACCESSLEVELTYPE = 
             ( SELECT MIN(aci.ACCESSLEVELTYPE) AS ACCESSLEVELTYPE
               FROM accesslevel aci
               WHERE aci.HEALTHSYSTEMID = hsc.HEALTHSYSTEMID              
             )
where c.fulfillmentmethod = 'Attach'
and c.display = 1
and uc.auditstatus <> 0
and ( (uc.auditstatus is null) 
   or (uc.auditstatus = 1 and uc.lastmodified > uc.auditdate) 
    ) ;
```

Tried at [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/736a7/23). You can test with data in the tables, to see which one fits your requirements and whether the joins should be on `hsc.HEALTHSYSTEMID = ac.HEALTHSYSTEMID` or with some other column.

Answer (score 2):

I feel that ypercube had a good answer that explained DENSE_RANK and how this can be used in relation to my query, so I have decided to accept his answer, but I want to post an additional answer detailing what I ended up doing.

Ultimately I think that I was able to accomplish this without the use of an analytic function.  Here is the query I have come up with below:

```
with minimumaccessleveltype as (
  select ac_.accessleveltype as accessleveltype from vs.accesslevel ac_
  where ac_.accesslevelid = 3
)
select uc.*
from vs.usercredential uc
inner join vs.users u on u.userid = uc.userid
inner join vs.credential c on c.credentialid = uc.credentialid
inner join vs.healthsystemcredential hsc on hsc.credentialid = c.credentialid
where c.fulfillmentmethod = 'Attach'
and c.display = 1
and uc.auditstatus <> 0
and ( (uc.auditstatus is null) or (uc.auditstatus = 1 and uc.lastmodified > uc.auditdate) )
and uc.lastmodified > TO_DATE('01-APR-2013','DD-MON-YYYY')
and exists (select null
  from vs.accesslevel ac
  where ac.healthsystemid = hsc.healthsystemid
  and hsc.accesslevelid = ac.accesslevelid
  and ac.accessleveltype <= (select accessleveltype from minimumaccessleveltype)
  )
and hsc.healthsystemid = 3
```

Notice that I have example values for my default filters, this was to demonstrate that the query actually returns and filters out data that I expect.

> AccessLevel ID 3: AccessLevelType = 6
>
> AccessLevel ID 2: AccessLevelType = 4
>
> AccessLevel ID 1: AccessLevelType = 1

I have one UserCredential record that meets the additional filtering and points to a Credential/HealthSystemCredential with an AccessLevel ID of 2.  When filtering on AccessLevel ID of 3 and 2 I expect this record to be returned.  When filtering on AccessLevel ID of 1 then the Type is too low and I expect it to be filtered out.

The query above seems to pass my unit test expectations so I am satisfied with this solution.  The Explain Plan has a low cost and it is fast.  The `WITH` clause will only ever return 1 record so even a CARTESIAN against this wouldn't affect the query.